# How to set the initial ration of the size of child elements of a Hdividedbox

Tags: apache-flex, layout

I have a Hdividedbox, which has three child elements.

I want to set the initial ration of sizes, such that the first one is 30%, the second is 40% & the third is 30% of the Hdividedbox's width.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed  - please see below for an example

```
<mx:HDividedBox width="100%" >
    <mx:Panel width="30%"/>
    <mx:Panel width="40%"/>
    <mx:Panel width="30%"/>
</mx:HDividedBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the child components' width to those specific percentages.